# Sort the header column in same page in jquery datatable

Tags: php, sorting, datatables

Im using jquery datatable version 1.9.4 When i goes to page 4 and click the header column to sort then the page automatically goes to starting page.As i have to select the row in page 4 and do the further works i need to sort in the same page?Could any one help?

Comment: Please add a [ Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Check out datatables webpage.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/50442

Basically in 1.9 can't sort the the current paginations results, but in 1.10 you may be able to work something out.